# How to update single files in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

The following command will upload the whole project to Google App Engine:

```
appcfg.py -R update C:/Users/user/Desktop/myproject/
```

However, I just made corrections locally to a single file of the project called index.php and would like to update the server version without uploading the whole project, which is large.

I have tried:

```
appcfg.py update C:/Users/user/Desktop/myproject/index.php
```

(notice I removed -R and also added the file name at the end) But this prints:

> Usage: appcfg.py [options] update  appcfg.py: error:
>   Directory does not contain an index.yaml configuration file.

any idea?

Answer (score 9):

My inexperience with google app engine made me post this question, but I got the answer on my own after a little while.

Hahahaha I just discovered something I did not know before. After making changes to the index.php file and finally decided to redeploy the whole thing. This time it took less than a minute to redeploy it to the server (the first time it took over 10).

It seems that the local appgine scans for local changes and submits just that instead of the whole project!

Therefore re-running:

```
appcfg.py -R update C:/Users/user/Desktop/myproject/
```

will update the files that were changed only.

Comment: We only upload files that have changed.

Comment: Thank goodness! I had compiled a library for google app engine and it was a 14mb jar which took up to 10 minutes to upload. If i had to upload that each time I was going to go appengineupdate, i would have pulled out my hair.

Answer (score -2):

i believe you can't. its all or nothing.